# Trying to understand error CS0120 when trying to use StreamReader in C#

Tags: c#, streamreader

I'm currently writing some code to produce a graph with grades from a .txt file. I am trying to use StreamReader to count the frequency of characters (so for example if the .txt file holds ADCBCBBBADEBCCBADBAACDCCBEDCBACCFEABBCBBBCCEAABCBB, I want it to say 9 A's, 17 B's 14 C's, 5 D's, 4 E's and 1 F). I include both the code and also include 1 error and a warning I receive when I compile the code:

> > example.cs(19,106): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement
> >
> > example.cs(20,27): error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.IO.TextReader.ReadLine()' c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.030319\mscorlib.dll: (location of symbol related to previous error)

I saw this and was baffled, tried to understand MSDN's explanation but it confused me more. Please can someone explain to me what I have done wrong and help me get my code working. Thanks!

```
`using System;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;

   namespace Assessment2
    {
       class fileAccess
       {
              static void Main(string[] args)
               {    

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Grades\grades_single.txt"));
                string line = StreamReader.ReadLine();
                int countOfAs = line.Count(x => x == 'A');

               }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Use the instance, viz : `string line = sr.ReadLine();`

Comment: You have a typo in your code. Remove the ; at the end of the using line. Then enclose the code in curly braces, and next time try to not follow blindly the comments in your previous questions

Comment: Your code doesn't compile..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN isn't that explicit on [CS0120](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s35hcfh7.aspx):

> In order to use a non-static field, method, or property, you must first create an object instance.

You did create an object instance `sr`, but it still doesn't compile. That is because you **need to call that method on that object reference** (`sr.ReadLine()`) instead of calling the method on the type (`StreamReader.ReadLine()`).

Your `using()` statement is ended with a semicolon (`;`), meaning you can't use it after that line. Remove the semicolon and enclose the following statement in braces (`{ }`), so you can use `sr`:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"path"))
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much for your help, I can finally finish this :P haha!